# Can't find MvxListItemView constructor

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am new to Xamarin, but need to create an Android app, so it is time to learn.

I heard about MvvmCross, and thought it would be a good addition, as it seems to simplify things a little.

I created a basic app, got a text box to show, that sort of thing.

I then tried adding a list view, using the [Dilbert](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DailyDilbert) example.

When I try and run a view with the MvxListItemView

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ProcessFormView);
}
```

I get this error.

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to find a constructor with
>   signature (Android.Content.Context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet) on
>   type MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListItemView.  Please provide
>   the missing constructor.

From what I can see the constructor is

```
public MvxListItemView(Context context, IMvxLayoutInflaterHolder layoutInflaterHolder, object dataContext, int templateId);
```

I cannot find any obvious differences in mine, and the demo.

Is there something I am missing, or maybe overlooked?

ProcessFormView.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Mvx.MvxListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Form"
             local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/FormItem" />
```

FormItem.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="Form Item" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Field" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What are your assembly linking settings for the Android project? i.e. the dropdown at Properties -> Android Options -> Linker -> Linking

Comment: Linking is: "None"

Comment: And are you able to run the demo successfully?

Comment: It is opening and running, it doesn't show anything. I haven't gone into it, but probably has to do with it not loading the feed or something.

It does not, however, give an error on `SetContentView`.

Comment: Ok, would you be able to include the content of your ProcessFormView and the item template your list uses in your question?

Comment: I have included it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me as though Android can't find the `MvxListItemView` contructor it's looking for because it's searching the wrong assemblies. You're using `Mvx.MvxListView` in your layout, but that's a shortcut that requires you registering the namespace abbreviation in your `Setup` class. There are three ways of fixing the problem:

**Option 1: AndroidViewAssemblies**

Change `Mvx.MvxListView` in your layout to `MvxListView`. Then, you need to provide Android with the assembly in which to find `MvxListView`, which is done with the `AndroidViewAssemblies` override in `Setup`:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies 
    => new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
{
    typeof(MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView).Assembly,
    typeof(MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListItemView).Assembly
};
```

This is the cleaner option, and the one I'd personally go with. Note that you'd need to follow the same two steps for every Mvx control in your app: removing the namespace from the layout, and registering it's assembly.

**Option 2: ViewNamespaceAbbreviations**

This option tells Android that `Mvx.MvxListView` actually means `MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListItemView`, and is also achieved with an override in `Setup`:

```
protected override IDictionary<string, string> ViewNamespaceAbbreviations
    => new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {
        "Mvx", "MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views"
    }
};
```

If you decide on option 2, be sure to leave your layouts unchanged (i.e. still use `Mvx.MvxListView`).

**Option 3: Laziness**

The easiest way to fix the issue is to fully qualify the namespace in your layout, by changing `Mvx.MvxListView` to `MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxListView`. The downside here is that you'd need to fully qualify every MvvmCross control you use, which is awkward and messy.

Comment: I tried number 2, and that worked.  I get a list of class names from the Form List.

Comment: A problem I have now,
I tried changing the template, so `local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/FormItemView"`.
I renamed the axml file.  The project doesn't build, with `The file "obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources" does not exist.`
if I remove `local:MvxItemTemplate` it builds, but with it, it does not.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly related, but, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any resources (layouts/drawables/etc) with hyphens in their file names?

Comment: No, I did check that, it's what I find if I Google the error.
http://imgur.com/a/wPFO7

Comment: Does a clean & rebuild fix the issue?

Comment: Cleaning, removing `local:MvxItemTemplate`, building, then adding it back and building does build. But cleaning and building with `local:MvxItemTemplate` does not. I suspect the build without the clean is not building everything.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, but if anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thank you, @luke-pothier

Comment: Building now, it seems the resource reference needs to be lowercase, so `local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/formitemview"`. The file name casing doesn't seem to matter, but it is now showing my view in the list.
@Luke, thank you again.

Comment: Nice! My pleasure :)